# Connecting Datastax outside Kubernetes to a Cassandra cluster in Kubernetes

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, datastax-java-driver

I have a Cassandra cluster running in Kubernetes on AWS (using the incubator Helm chart). When I expose the nodes with a load balancer, Datastax is unable to directly connect to the nodes in the way it wants because it tries to use the IPs internal to the Kubernetes network. But it can still successfully read and write through the loadbalancer. [This is not recommended however](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningAntiPatterns.html#planningAntiPatterns__AntiPatLoadBal) so I am looking for a proper solution.

Is there a way to have datastax connect properly with this setup? Would it require changing the `cassandra.yaml` inside the container (yuck)?

Comment: I would be also helpful if you post your cassandra.yml

Comment: I just used the Cassandra helm chart on the official helm repo. Except I added a single loadbalancer that targets the Cassandra pods

Answer (score 4):

First of all. You can't use LoadBalancer for this purpose.

Set up the service like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cassandra
  name: cassandra
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9042
    nodePort: 30042
  selector:
    app: cassandra
```

The nodePort will be available outside the Kubernetes cluster. The nodePort has to be between 30000-32767.

From datastax driver, connect to K8S_NODE_IP:NODEPORT (not the pod ip).

Comment: I still get an error with Datastax trying to connect to the nodes, since the nodes don't view itself (or its peers) as the `K8S_NODE_IP`s. Sounds like this could work if I also modify the `cassandra.yaml`s, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: What error do you get? I tested it myself and it works fine. Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/A5kHGQGM

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use an address translator at the driver:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/address_resolution/

However note that you will loose driver side features like token aware load balancing etc.

The best approach is to provide direct connectivity from your app to all the C* nodes so it can establish connections to each node.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Kubernetes service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to expose the pods in your Deployment or StatefulSet.  The service could be either a [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) or [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) port so that you have external access.

You will also have to add a [`Selector`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors) on both your service and your Deployment/StatefulSet so that your service can attach the right [`Endpoints`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear about my setup. I already tried a LoadBalancer and it is non-ideal

Comment: Does it need to use the internal IPs? Can Cassandra publish another IP? If it can publish the hostIP then you can use `NodePort`

Comment: I believe that would require me to modify `cassandra.yaml` inside the pod, which takes away some of the draw of using Kubernetes here

Comment: Well you would need to modify your deployment or statefulset definition with however the helm chart deploys it.

Comment: Cassandra has listen & broadcast addresses, so your setup need to configure them correctly